# Where can I find the Quick Start for Doctor Who: AiTaS?

Tags: doctor-who-roleplaying-game

My wife and I are Whovians and I am a long time RPG nerd, and recently I discovered *Doctor Who: Adventures in Time and Space* which looks (and judging by reviews *is*) awesome.

The problem is that I am not willing to invest money sight unseen to try out a game that I am not sure that I will be able to GM well or even like.

Does anyone know where I can find free quick start rules for *DW:AiTaS*, preferably also with pregenerated characters and a prefab adventure? I know the downloadable version on DriveThruRPG says it comes with quick start rules, but I don't know where I can find *just* the quick start.

Answer (score 4):

Cubicle7—the publishers of the game—have a [section devoted to free downloads](http://www.cubicle7.co.uk/free-samples/) for Doctor Who: Adventures in Time and Space.  Specifically, the [Read This First section](http://www.cubicle7.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/DWAITAS-Eleventh-Doctor-Edition-ReadThisFirst.pdf) of the book mentioned on DTRPG that you asked about is available there with a layout of the basic rules and such.

There are also other free downloads there, so I'd check it out.

Comment: thank you, i hadnt found the "read this first" portion unfortunatly it isnt complete enough, it references page 7 when there are only 2 pages. also no pregenerated characters and only the quickest glance at the character sheet, with no break down as to what the actual different characters DO. just by looking at it you can tell it is incomplete. but thank you very much because this puts me on the right track to continue my own search.